# How to render a photo via server.js file to webpage using express in node js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, image, rendering

I am currently working on a project where I have to do a lookup page in node js. The lookup needs to lookup an id (entered in my rendered index.ejs file by the user) and display the information retrieved from a database. Information recieved includes the id, name, email, and a picture. So far I have figured out how to render text into the ejs file however I cannot find any information on how to live render an image from the server.js file. I've looked for ways to render an "" tag through the text so I can load it that way and I have looked for ways to render the image itself but have only been able to find tutorials on how to make a html file with a hard coded image inside, and render the whole file, which would not allow me to do the lookup. Can anyone suggest a way to do this and/or link me to somewhere where I can get the information on how to do this?

.

Key details (as I do not know what you need to know):

File type: ejs

File render type: res.render()

Main file: server.js

.

Im sorry if this isnt much to go on as I am new to node js.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have picture path in database or complete image file in database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have full image in the database, then

There is **pic** attribute to the res.render in express.js
An example of how you can render image is below.

```
var pic = "./public/images/"+collection_id+"/"+photo_id+".png"; //(You can get the image from database and assign here)
var comments = "bla bla bla";

res.render('index', { title: 'Viewer' , pic: pic , comments: comments } );
```

In your ejs:

```
<img src='<%= pic %>' />
```

Comment: :O Thank you so much! I had tried this before but it didn't work. I must've had something wrong. Thank you!